# How do I set a fixed background image for a PHP file?

Tags: php, html

I have an .html file with a login form and wish to recreate it and save it as a .php file. However, I'm encountering difficulties with setting the background image and other CSS related stuff.

Below is my code for the .php which I'm sure it won't provide guidance to answering my question, but I don't know where to start. I've checked W3schools and many other sites.

A great start to helping me out would on how I would include a .CSS file in .PHP file. Perhaps giving me the a quick source code example. Also, the code to set a fixed background 
image would be amazing.

```
<?php

$url = 'C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\bg.jpg';

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>This is a test</title>

<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<p>This is a test.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is fundamentally not a question about PHP, or about programming at all, really -- it's a basic web design question.

Comment: If you familiar with HTML you should know

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov, If he was familiar with HTML, he wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @Brad that's true, but he noted it in the first line :)

Comment: instead of wasting your time criticizing my coding abilities, perhaps you could provide some constructive help ?

Comment: Exactly! Why can't people just provide some help or just don't reply if it's not gonna be of any help

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer.

```
<?php
$profpic = "bg.jpg";
?>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
background-image: url('<?php echo $profpic;?>');
}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hey</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer for future on-lookers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good coding to put PHP code into CSS

```
body
{
    background-image:url('bg.png');
}
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have anything to do with PHP... just CSS.

Your CSS is correct, but your browser won't typically be able to open what you have put in for a URL.  At a minimum, you'll need a `file:` path.  It would be best to reference the file by its relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider have other php files included if you're going to derive a website from it. Instead of doing all the css/etc in that file, you can do

```
<head>
    <?php include_once('C:\Users\George\Documents\HTML\style.css'); ?>
    <title>Title</title>
</hea>
```

Then you can have a separate CSS file that is just being pulled into your php file. It provides some "neater" coding.