# GDlib PHP - png to gif returns background transparent to black

Tags: php, png, gd, gif

When trying to convert PNG to GIF, return transparent to black:

```
$file = "example.png"

$whf = getimagesize($file); 
$wf = $whf[0];
$hf = $whf[1];

$h = "100";
$w = "100";

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$imgi = imagecreatefrompng($file);

// Here means to be some magic code...

imagecopyresampled($img, $imgi, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $wf, $hf);
imagegif($img, "example.gif");

imagedestroy($img);
```

Codes I've tryed but nothing:

1º:

```
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagecolortransparent($img, 127<<24);
```

2º:

```
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

This works! But with one detail. You need absolute transparent background without "png gradients transparencies". Imagick uses half gradient transparencies to absolute transparent and other half to absolute plain. Thanks isalgueiro!

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
```

Comment: The answer could be in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresample

Comment: Nope, this work for png to png, but not for png to gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call [imagecolorallocate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) to get the color reference and pass that to [imagecolortransparent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php):

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
```

Comment: Returns black background

Comment: This is the right way, but you need to re-convert the image after. Btw, don't forget to set a background.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention to set the same background color. You can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php for an idea, check the comment zone. Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752451/how-do-i-set-a-fixed-background-image-for-a-php-file