# background image of div element can't show in php file

Tags: php, css

I had a .html file which uses css to assign div's background-image.

The thing is when it's .html it works, I want to change it to .php and I can't figure out how to make the image show.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752451/how-do-i-set-a-fixed-background-image-for-a-php-file) question and the answer didn't help me, using `url('<?php echo $img;?'>` and `<?php $img="bg.gif";?>` didn't work.

this is sample code :

```
<?php
$bg = "bg.gif"; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar-sy"> <head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">    
<style> 
html,body {margin: 0px; padding:0px;background-image:url('<?php echo $bg;?>'); }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">    
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">        
      </div>
      <div id="links">        
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="mainimg">      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the body doesn't get filled with the image, although I have the image right with the php file in the same folder.

So what to do ?

### Edit

I tried absolute path and still the image doesn't show, also I'm running linux mint 17.1 64 bit, "bg.gif" has all the permissions it needs(group can read and write, other can read and write too).

Inspecting with my browser(opera), it says "failed to load resource , server responded with 404 not found".

Comment: try with absolute path

Comment: Try inspecting the element in your browser and checking what's the issue. It'll show you from what path it's trying to load the image from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, When inspecting from my browser I forgot to see where it looks.

I was using codeignitor , the website is acessed from index.php so when you say `$bg="bg.gif"` it will look for the image under `pathtoyourproject/index.php/bg.gif`, I solved it by moving the image besides bg.gif and put `$bg="../bg.gif"` so it doesn't look under index.php.

As for the absolute path, if the absolute path was /var/www/... then it was looking under http://localhost/var/www/... which is equivalent to looking under /var/www/html/var/www/... , that's why it didn't work.